# How to set initial observable value in Angularjs2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, rxjs, observable

```
export class RulesComponent {
  items: Observable<Array<string>>;
  term = new FormControl();

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.term.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.searchService.search('rules', term));
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

  constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp) {}

  search(name: string, term: string) {
    var search = new URLSearchParams();
    search.set('search', term);
    return this.jsonp
                .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000' , { search })
                .map(this.extractData)
                .json();
  }
}
```

I want search() to be called before `term` value changes and set `items` value to search result while page is loading, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but today I was solving the same issue. Correct solution is:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.term.valueChanges
      .startWith('')
      .debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.searchService.search('rules', term));
    this.term.setValue('search text here', {emitEvent:true});
}
```

Important is `.startWith(initialValue)` part that will emit initial value for observable. More is described 
[in ReactiveX documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/startwith.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to trigger the search in the ngOnInit() function of the component like this.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.term.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.searchService.search('rules', term));
    this.term.setValue('search text here', {emitEvent:true});
}
```

Link to A2 FormControl documentation for reference:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work: `Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.term.next is not a function.`

Comment: Sorry I have a similar implementation but 'term' for me is of type 'Subject'. Basically you need to set term in a way that will trigger the search in ngOnInit.

Comment: Can you give it another shot? I updated it so that it SHOULD work with a formcontrol object. Never used those but thats what I was able to gather from the documentation.

Comment: Still don't trigger term.valueChanges

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`this.term.setValue("New York");`